# Passing an environment variable from the host machine to a container via Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So i want to have in my container an environment variable called (oldhostname) of the host's hostname env variable (not the container's) , and i want to execute this : ( HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T " ) in my container as well to have the history formatted , this is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM kathara/quagga
ARG old=`hostname`
ENV oldhostname=$old
CMD HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

Comment: Since the Dockerfile is built once and the image gets reused, you can't set this variable there.  Use the `docker run -e` option or a Docker Compose `environment:` block to set it when you launch the container.

Comment: Or you use docker-compose

Comment: @DavidMaze the problem is i don't use `docker run` to start a container from the image, instead i have to use `kathara lstart` , i guess in this case i have to use Docker compose , right ?

Comment: and for the command `CMD HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T " ` i don't know why it doesn't execute.

Comment: If the base image has an entrypoint, that command (wrapped in `sh -c`) gets passed as parameters to the entrypoint, and it is up to that entrypoint to handle it (many SO questions feature entrypoint scripts that completely ignore `CMD`).  If not, then that is the only command the container runs, and I'd expect it to promptly exit with status code 0.